# Do IBMSBT has a built in XML to JSON converter in JAVA?

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I'm trying to figure out how to convert XML to JSON in IBMSBT because not all CNX api's and Object does not support tranformation out of the box. (example: Profile) I need to return JSON only.

So before I add yet another 3. party project. Do IBMSBT have a built in XML to JSON converter ?

Thanks for any reply helping me in the right direction

Comment: The entity you get back is a a Java Object,  just put the Java Object into the JSONJavaObject and serialize it.  thanks Paul

Answer (score 0):

What @PaulBastide is saying: use the

```
com.ibm.commons.util.io.json
```

package in com.ibm.commonsxxx.jar, which is part of the SBT